# How to disable gray box that displays typed-in text

Tags: android

[image]

How can I disable the gray box that appears in middle of screen as shown above?

Comment: where is gay box?are you talking about dssds  box?

Comment: yes....in the middle of screen

Comment: That looks like some weird debug feature, or maybe your custom keyboard, or a custom skin on Android.